# Why isn’t my shaft moving?

Tags: motor, wheeled-robot, mechanism, motion, gearing

When I put my shaft through the vehicle body (small robot) and have the motor attached to it through two rotating gears, the shaft isn’t rotating?

I think it’s due to how the hole diameter is the same as the shaft diameter? Do I need to put a component in between the hole and shaft to allow rotation please?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Attach Axel, motor and gears to 2 wheels](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/21736/attach-axel-motor-and-gears-to-2-wheels)

Comment: if the hole is the same diameter as the shaft, then how could you insert something between the hole and the shaft? ... has it not occured to you to make the hole slightly larger?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Ralph Faure, but please don't post the same question twice. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works. Also, the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) has good advice on how to write a good question. If you edit your question to fit our community guidelines we can reopen it for you.